# Solving $T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{4}) + \log n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

Solve following recursive relation $T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{4}) + \log n$ without resorting to the master theorem. I've tried substitution method but it didn't work. I don't know whether there is a method using calculus for solving problems like this. According to WA, the answer is $T(n)\in \Theta(\sqrt n)$.

After substitution, I've found  that $$T(n) = 2^iT(\frac{n}{2^{2i}}) + \sum_{k=0}^{i-1} 2^k\log(\frac{n}{2^{2k}})$$

and don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: How did you try the substitution method, and how did it not work? What happens if you look at, e.g., $n=4^i$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Please see the edit.

Comment: @S.H.W What happens when you plug $i=\frac{1}{2}\log n$ (binary logarithm) in your expression?

Comment: @ClementC. It becomes $$T(1) \sqrt{n} + \sum_{k = 0}^{\frac{\log n}{2} - 1} 2^k\log(\frac{n}{2^k})$$.

Comment: @S.H.W Yes. Can you compute the sum? Note that said sum has a trivial upper bound of $O(\sqrt{n}\log n)$, so if you could compute it in a better way, it looks like you should get the right answer of $O(\sqrt{n})$...

Comment: @ClementC. My main problem is about the sum. I don't know how to compute that.

Comment: (also, are you **sure** the sum you wrote is correct, and that it's really $2^k$ instead of $2^{2k}$ in the denominator)? @S.H.W

Comment: @ClementC. You're right, thanks. I edited the formula.

Comment: @ClementC. Do you have any idea about computing the sum?

Comment: @S.H.W To reiterate my comment, I suggest looking at the _special case_ $n=4^i$; you should find that all of those messy-looking terms simplify.

Comment: @S.H.W Yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's write $s = \frac{1}{2}\log n$, so that it suffices in order to conclude to bound the sum
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{s-1} 2^k \log\frac{2^{2s}}{2^{2k}}=
2\sum_{k=0}^{s-1} (s-k)2^k\tag{1}
$$
(plugging $i=s$ in the formula you obtained, as the first term $2^sT(n/2^{2s})$ then becomes $O(\sqrt{n})$. We then have, from (1),
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{s-1} (s-k)2^k
= \sum_{\ell=1}^s \ell \cdot 2^{s-\ell}
= 2^s \sum_{\ell=1}^s \ell \cdot 2^{-\ell}
\leq 2^s \sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \ell \cdot 2^{-\ell} = O(2^s) = O(\sqrt{n}) \tag{2} 
$$
the second-to-last equality since the sum $\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \ell \cdot 2^{-\ell}$ converges (and therefore is an absolute constant), and the last by definition of $s$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome, @S.H.W.

Comment: @ClementC. If possible, can you look at the question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4850519/reccurence-solution-no-using-master-theorem-that-tn-3tn-3n-log-n-t1-1

Answer (score 2):

In
$T(n) 
= 2T(\frac{n}{4}) + \log n
$,
let $n = 4^m$.
This becomes
$T(4^m) 
= 2T(\frac{4^m}{4}) + \log (4^m)
= 2T(4^{m-1}) + m\log 4
$.

Divide this by $2^m$ to get
$\dfrac{T(4^m)}{2^m} 
= \dfrac{2T(4^{m-1}) + m\log 4}{2^m}
= \dfrac{T(4^{m-1})}{2^{m-1}}+\dfrac{m\log 4}{2^m}
$.

Writing
$U(m)
=\dfrac{T(4^m)}{2^m}
$,
this becomes
$U(m)
=U(m-1)+\dfrac{m\log 4}{2^m}
$.

This now telescopes,
so you need to get
$U(n)-U(0)
=\sum_{m=1}^n \dfrac{m\log 4}{2^m}
$.

Then you can work backwards
to get $T(4^m)$.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate about solving $U(m)
=U(m-1)+\dfrac{m\log 4}{2^m}$ please?

Comment: A special case of $\sum nx^n$.

Comment: And after solving that, we should use $U(m)
=\dfrac{T(4^m)}{2^m}$ to get $T(n)$. Is that true?

Comment: You also don't need to compute the sum. You just need to know it's bounded, which holds because $\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \ell/2^\ell$ converges. (This is also what is used in my answer.)

Comment: If all that is needed is to show convergence, then you are correct.