# Reccurence solution no using Master Theorem that $T(n)=3T(n/3)+n/\log n, T(1)=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, recurrence-relations

I try to solve $T(n)=3T(n/3)+n/\log n, T(1)=1$ recurrence relation without using the Master Theorem. I get the following,

$$T(3^k)=3T(3^{k-1})+\frac{3^k}{log(3^k)}$$

I don't know `parameter translation` very well, for example, by saying $T(3^k)=S(k)$. However, I try to do the following conversion, but I can't go on from there forward. I don't know what the blue part is going to be.

$$S(k)=3S(k-1)+\color{blue}{\frac{3^k}{log(3^k)}}$$

Can it also be solved by not making use of `parameter translation`?

It is not homework or assignment, but just to enjoy and learn. I'm toying with them as my hobby.

Comment: In $T(3^k)=S(n)$, how $k$ is related to $n$?

Comment: @user58697 Yes, as I said, I'm not good at parameter translation. It should be $T(3^k)=S(k)$. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have reached the point
$$
S(k)=\color{red}{3}\cdot S(k-1)+\color{blue}{\frac{3^k}{k \log(3)}} \tag{1}
$$
Almost there! Now set $R(k) = \frac{S(k)}{3^k}$ to get rid of that annoying factor $\color{red}{3}$: dividing (1) by $3^k$ on each side, you get
$$
R(k)=R(k-1)+\frac{1}{k \log(3)} \tag{2}
$$
which you should be able to solve.

**Hint:**

> Essentially, summing from $k=1$ to $K$ on both sides will be give a telescoping series, and you'll end up with $R(K) = R(0) + \frac{1}{\log 3} \sum_{k=1}^K \frac{1}{k}$, and then remember that that last sum is the Harmonic number, which is $\Theta(\log K)$.

Once you have the asymptotics of $R(k)$, you can get those of $S(k)$ (multiply by $3^k$), then finally of $T(n)$.

Comment: Thank you. But, I don't understand $R(k) = \frac{S(k)}{3^k}$; as I say in my question, I'm terrible at parameter translations. How did/do we do this transformation? And how do you get rid of 3 with it? By dividing (1) by $3^k$ on each side we obtain $(\frac{3⋅S(k−1)}{3^k}) + \frac{1}{k \log(3)} $. Don't we?

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire yes, and $3/3^k = 1/3^{k-1}$. And that's what you want (and why we did it)! As $S(k-1)/3^{k-1}=R(k-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that $\log 3^k$ is $k \log 3$, so the recurrence becomes

$$S(k) = 3S(k-1) + \dfrac{3^k}{k\log 3}$$

Expand $S(k-1)$:

$$S(k) = 3\left(3S(k-2) + \dfrac{3^{k-1}}{(k-1)\log3}\right) + \dfrac{3^k}{k\log 3} =$$
$$= 9S(k-2) + \dfrac{3^k}{(k-1)\log 3} + \dfrac{3^k}{k\log 3} =$$
$$=9S(k-2) + \dfrac{3^k}{\log 3}\left(\dfrac{1}{k} + \dfrac{1}{k-1}\right)$$

Do you see the pattern?

Keep going to obtain

$$S(n) = 3^kS(0) + \dfrac{3^k}{\log 3}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}\dfrac{1}{n}$$,

where the sum is approximately $\ln k$

Comment: But some found it out as $T(3^k)=\Theta(3^k\log k)$ ? How ln k ?

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire there is no difference. They are the same by a constant factor

Answer (score 0):

With $a > 0$

$$
S(k)=a S(k-1) + \frac{a^k}{k}
$$

It is a linear recurrence then it has the linearity benefits:

$$
S(k) = S_h(k)+S_p(k)
$$

where

$$
\cases{
S_h(k)-a S_h(k-1) = 0\\
S_p(k)-a S_p(k-1) = \frac{a^k}{k}
}
$$

The homogeneous has as solution

$$
S_h(k) = c_0 a^k
$$

and a particular solution can be obtained by assuming $S_p(k) = c_0(k)a^k$ so after substitution we have

$$
c_0(k) a^k - a c_0(k-1)a^{k-1} = \frac{a^k}{k}
$$

or

$$
c_0(k)-c_0(k-1) = \frac 1k
$$

then $c_0(k) = \sum_{i=1}^k\frac 1i$ hence

$$
S_p(k) = a^k\sum_{i=1}^k\frac 1i
$$

and

$$
S(k) = \left(c_0+\sum_{i=1}^k\frac 1i\right)a^k
$$

Now going backwards, as $k = \log_a n$ we have

$$
T(n) = \left(c_0+\sum_{i=1}^{\log_a n}\frac 1i\right)n
$$

then

$$
T(n) = \mathcal{O}(n)
$$